# if it possible reconfigure a jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
jframe to default show rectangle.
```

i want to know if it possible we show  it similar to a circle?

and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have non-rectangular JFrames. The simple way to do this is to use AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(Window, Shape). Read the page below for more details.

Someone else mentioned that it's possible to do this using the Robot class, but that unnecessary. Java now supports this natively where possible.

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/03/18/translucent-and-shaped-swing-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/swinghks_hack41/index.html) describes a clever hack that allows you to implement non-rectangular and translucent frames.  You can apparently do it (non-portably of course) using native code hacks.